# Populate public string from another cs file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have 2 .cs files `feed.sc` & `clickTest.sc` in clickTest.sc i have a `public string LinkID = "";` with i like to populate with information from `feed.sc`
[image]

Not sure if or how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `GameObject.Find` to find the **GameObject** the `clickTest` script is attached to. Then use `GetComponent` to get the instance of `clickTest` script that is attached to that **GameObject**. The rest is easy.

```
GameObject tempObj = GameObject.Find("Canvas/LiveFeed/Content/feeditem 0");
clickTest cTest = tempObj.GetComponent<clickTest>();
cTest.LinkID = "Hello!";
```

Comment: You sir are a genius!

Comment: @kevinver lol that's the first question for unity beginners. Don't forget to accept the answer. +1 for putting a picture up which made your question easier to understand.

Comment: had to wait 5 minutes ;)