# Public Static Boolean will not appear in the Inspector

Tags: c#, debugging, variables, unity-game-engine, static

I have looked and looked and looked for answers but I cannot get this Boolean variable to appear in the inspector no matter what I try. I am trying to make the variable public so that I can diagnose a bug in my game. If I make the exact same variable in another script it shows up, but for some reason this one won't.

Here is my code:

```
public class LB : MonoBehaviour {
    public static bool canStep;

    void Start (){
        canStep = true;
    }

    void OnTriggerExit (Collider tf){
        if (tf.gameObject.name == "Player") {
            canStep = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your entire script? Because items will not show in the inspector if there are any errors in your script.

Comment: never, ever, use "static" in Unity.  in general it is irrelevant in an ECS setting.  (there are some very advanced uses, but totally irrelevant to what you are doing.)

Comment: hi @kramb.  it has nothing to do with that.  it would be meaingless to serialize to the Inspector display a "static" - in general static has no meaning in an ECS system like Unity.  you "can't do that".

Comment: If you're just trying to see the value of non-serialized variables in the inspector, an alternative is to use the [Debug Mode](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InspectorOptions.html) in Unity. You won't be able to change their values, but you will be able to observe them in real-time (which seems to be what you want here).

Comment: There are no errors in the script and I need the variable to be static to call it from another class. Is there another way to do so?

Comment: Serlite: The script is going to be applied to multiple of the same game object and i need to be able to see what it is doing in each individual instance.

Comment: A static variable only has a single value for the class.  You won't be able to see different values for different instances since they all share the same value.

Comment: Hi Samuel.  *"I need the variable to be static"*  You CAN NOT USE "static" in Unity.  (By the way - note that even if you thought it was working, *it was not working*)  I have shown you in the answer exactly how to access variables from another script

Comment: Please update your question accordingly - based on your comments, your goal isn't really to get the "variable to appear in the inspector" so you "can diagnose a bug", but rather "make the variable accessible to other scripts". Otherwise, it's possible you'll attract answers that don't actually reach your objectives.

Comment: hi @Serlite  The question seems fine?  user is making a mistake (using "static") and the question is why it is not working.  the answer is basically "remove "static" keyword".  no big deal...

Comment: @JoeBlow Yeah, upon re-reading the comments I think I misinterpreted one of them. =P Heh, you've got a pretty strong stance against static.

Comment: heh just for pedagogic reasons

Comment: hi @SamuelBailey please TICK any answer to keep the board tidy, and get points as a new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's simply

```
 public bool canStep;
```

that's all there is to it.  (Never use "static" in Unity.)

Your class must not be called "LB".  It should be called "LongBoard", or whatever the case is.

---

Note. I'm guessing you need to access "canStep" from ANOTHER script.  Let's say, from another MonoBehaviour called Jumping.  Just do this

```
public class LB : MonoBehaviour
{
public LongBoard longBoard; // DRAG TO CONNECT in Inspector

.. and then ..

 void Example()
 {
 if ( longBoard.canStep )
   {
   }
 }

}
```

Comment: Yeah. static variables don't display in the Editor because they can't be serialized.

Comment: damn right.  additionally it's almost impossible Samuel really wants to use a static.  where's that great QA you had where you explained how to access variables from another script recently ...

Comment: I had it named something else but i thought that might have been the problem so i made a new script with this name. I need to call it in another class and from what i understand i need it to be static to do so. Is there another way to call it in another class?

Comment: @JoeBlow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37074880/populate-public-string-from-another-cs-file/37075018#37075018 I think that's what he's looking for.

Comment: hi Samuel.  Take your time and read the following.  ***YOU CAN NOT USE "STATIC" IN UNITY***.  Is that clear now?

Comment: I have just explained at great length how you access it from another script.  Also see the link by Programmer.  or read this  http://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Accessing_Other_Game_Objects.html  Note - you don't use "static" in Unity.  Make it so in your mind, you forget you ever saw the word "static"  :)  Then you'll be all set!

Comment: @JoeBlow I apologize I did not see this link earlier and I never knew that you couldn't use static variables. I am relatively new to unity and coding in general.

Comment: no problem at all @SamuelBailey SO is here to help !  please be sure to remember to "TICK" some answer, so you get points and you are not moderated as a new user.  cheers.  don't hesitate to ask more questions

Comment: you can use static in Unity. simply you won't get those variable to be serialized but static fields are perfectly fine to be used!

Comment: hi @Heisenbug  you can not meaningfully use static in a monobehavior on a component-based system.  and of course, you cannot serliaze it or use it as an Inspector variable **as the question was asking**.  Right?  of course, there are very advanced uses of "static" in certain classes in Unity.  but it is "totally wrong" for what the OP was doing, trying to use it to "get a value in another script", not to mention that he had "different scripts" and so on

Comment: It's not a very advanced usage. It's just a static value, like every other static variable in C#. You said "Never use "static" in Unity" and YOU "CAN NOT USE "STATIC" IN UNITY". That's wrong and misleading imho. The only right comment is by @Programmer :  "static variables don't display in the Editor because they can't be serialized".

Comment: @Heisenbug I understand what Joe is saying. The reason the OP used static is likely because he wants to access the variable directly from another script. He doesn't know how to use getComponent to accomplish that so he went for static variable. There are few exceptions where static is fine but this is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

why are you using static keyword, You don't need variables to be static to be manipulated by other scripts, they just have to be public. just  assigned it in the inspector, so you're all set,you should generally not use static unless you specifically mean for only one instance or you know what you are doing.

Comment: hi @samuel you should "Tick" this answer since you need to Tick an answer as a new user.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly show the static var in inspector as Dreamora stated in this [thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/show-static-variables-in-the-inspector.64849/):

> No, only monobehaviour instance variables show up not class variables
>   that have nothing to do with the component on the object at all
>   technically

but actually here is the trick to watch the static var in inspector. use another non static var to watch the static var in inspector simple.

```
public static int myStaticVart;
public int myStaticVarInspector;
void Update()
{
    myStaticVarInspector = myStaticVart.
}
```